# How does IE's Privacy options affect javascript's ability to save cookies?

Tags: webserver, javascript, privacy, cookies, p3p

I'm looking at IE's privacy options screen and am trying to figure out how it breaks javascript, workarounds to that, and how I can gracefully degrade my user experience.

Is there a guide that directly describes the IE reaction to the P3P header?

How about corresponding Javascript samples for each known good/known bad example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that, to the client-side programmer, it doesn't matter how IE privacy settings break javascript -- If you're going to support graceful degradation, then the cause of the javascript failure doesn't matter to the programmer. All that matters is that whatever caused the javascript to "break" the code can handle it.

In that regard, it sounds to me like you are wanting a list of things to do when programming javascript graceful degradation. This kind of question would belong in StackOverflow.com, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript has good information (including a "best practices" section at bottom).

If you specifically want to know how to do unobtrusive JS in regards to making sure your site is not dependent on cookies, then SO is still the place to ask that.

---

Also, P3P information does not affect the javascript (except for a few edge cases in MSIE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707780/is-p3p-response-information-accessible-from-javascript/7707863#7707863)